# How can I copy an FTP link to the Windows sytem clipboard?

Tags: java, windows, swing, ftp, clipboard

I'm working on a project - desktop application (Java, [Swing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swing_%28Java%29)) which needs to copy a link to FTP files to the system clipboard for user to be able to paste those files in Explorer.

I use data flavor with `mime-type text/uri-list` and representation class `java.lang.String`. I put a link to the FTP file to the clipboard, but Windows does not want to paste it in Explorer.

Code, trying to copy the link to the clipboard looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

    final DataFlavor dataFlavor = new DataFlavor("text/uri-list; class=java.lang.String");
    Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    clipboard.setContents(new Transferable() {
        @Override
        public DataFlavor[] getTransferDataFlavors() {
            return new DataFlavor[]{dataFlavor};
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor flavor) {
            return dataFlavor.equals(flavor);
        }

        @Override
        public Object getTransferData(DataFlavor flavor) throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException {
            if (dataFlavor.equals(flavor)){
                return "ftp://127.0.0.1:2323/folder/file.txt";
            } 
            return null;
        }
    }, new ClipboardOwner() {
        @Override
        public void lostOwnership(Clipboard clipboard, Transferable contents) {
            System.out. println("Lost clipboard owner");
        }
    });
 }
```

I also tried to use other representation classes (InputStream, byte array, and char array). As I understand I need to put to the clipboard a list of java.util.list and use dataflavor DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor, but I don't know how convert an FTP link to a file.

What is the right way to put an FTP link in the clipboard?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no such thing as special URI clipboard contents in Windows. Just copy the URI as a plain `String`:

```
Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
StringSelection s=new StringSelection("ftp://127.0.0.1:2323/folder/file.txt");
clipboard.setContents(s, s);
```

If you want to create a Desktop shortcut file you just need to create a plain text file with the suffix `.URL` and write the following contents to it:

```
[InternetShortcut]
URL=ftp://127.0.0.1:2323/folder/file.txt
```

Comment: No, this does not work. This code copy simple text to system clipboard.

Comment: How do you tell the difference? Or, in other words: which software does something else? When I copy a URL from the Explorer, the result is the same: having a textual representation of it in the clipboard.

Comment: Textual representation is not enaugh. OS need links to files, not text.

Comment: After copying files in explorer I can see in clipboard dataflavors for mime types application/x-java-file-list, application/x-java-url, text/uri-list, text/plain.
Having this data in clipboard I can paste file in any other folder, on desktop
After executing your example I can see in clipboard dataflavors with mime types application/x-java-url, application/x-java-text-encoding, text/uri-list, text/plain, but no dataflavor for application/x-java-file-list and paste in explorer or desktop is unavailable

Comment: Data for mime type application/x-java-file-list: [, 䁼, , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , , 退샄ǎ退샄ǎ退샄ǎ, , ಺file1.png] I think this question cannot be solved in java

Comment: After copying *files* you see the file-list DataFlavor. You can copy files using [`DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/DataFlavor.html#javaFileListFlavor). But FTP URIs are not files.

Comment: If you see a file list after copying an FTP location, check what files the list contain. I bet, it will be a copy inside the %tmp% directory. Of course, you can do the same, download the FTP file into a temp file and copy that file to the clipboard.

Comment: You think that after user press Ctrl+C in explorer windows copy files from ftp server to tmp directory? And what if size of those files is about gigabytes?  I dont think so. I think windows copy to clipboard links with special datafloavor.

Comment: No, it does not copy it immediately as it will get notified when the receiver wants the data for performing the ‹paste› operation. So it just *tells* that the data are available as files and creates the files when they are requested. In theory, your Java program can do the same and create the temporary file when `getTransferData` is invoked with the file flavor. But I experienced in existing Java implementations that the JRE itself calls `getTransferData` immediately making any attempt for lazy creating worthless. I don’t know whether there’s a workaround.

Comment: If you know how it works, please, give me an example